# jQuery.LocalScroll not working with cloned menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [jQuery.LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) plugin to allow my website visitors to navigate my site with a smooth scrolling effect. It's working great with original header menu. But I am trying to function with cloned header. Here is the code:

```
$('.sf-menu').localScroll({lazy: true});

if($('header.header-sticky').length == 0) {
    $('[data-sticky-header="true"]').before($('[data-sticky-header="true"]').clone().addClass("header-sticky"));
}
```

An here is the HTML Markup

```
<header class="op_style" data-sticky-header="true">
    <div class="clearfix header-desktop">

            <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
                    <div class="site-logo">
                            <h1><a href="#" rel="home">Logo</a></h1>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-9 medium-9 columns">
                    <nav class="main-nav">
                            <ul id="menu-for-one-page-portfolio" class="sf-menu right">
                                <li><a href="#hello">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                            </ul>              
                    </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your HTML too to allow mocking up answers?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, I am reconnecting the `localscroll` to the new element after cloning. HTML markup added. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use .clone(true) - it clones an element with all event handlers to it